# SBT: Accessing setting values of subprojects in scala build

Tags: scala, sbt

I have an SBT (0.13.2) multiproject, and have a group of subprojects declared in separate build file, like this:

```
object SubBuilds extends Build {
  lazy val sub_project1 = Project("sub_project1",  file("sub/Project1")).dependsOn(Build.core)
  lazy val sub_project2 = Project("sub_project2", file("sub/Project2")).dependsOn(Build.core)
  ...
}
```

Each subproject has its own `build.sbt` file where `name := "..."` can be specified.

I can access the list of projects in `root` build simply as `SubBuilds.projects` and get `Seq[Project]`. It has supposedly property `settings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]]` which I hoped to use, but I'm completely stuck how I can get value from any of those properties. I can find a setting with key `name` but it has nothing like `value`.

How can I achieve this: get, say, `name` property using Project instance in scala builds?

**Update**:
I should note that I intend to use it inside of other task, I tried answer by @eugene-yokota but it produces "Illegal dynamic reference" during build compilation.

```
object CustomTasks {
  /** Task to display Subprojects */
  val subList = taskKey[Unit]("Display subprojects")

  val subListTask = subList := {
    SubBuilds.projects foreach { a =>
      val v = (name in a).value
      println(s"Subproject ${a.id}, $v")
    }
  }
}

[error] .../project/CustomTasks.scala:164: Illegal dynamic reference: a
[error]       val v = (name in a).value
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Building on Eugene's answer. The correct solution is indeed Scopes, but you're using it wrong, I guess.

The code should be more or less like this

```
lazy val nameAndProjectID = Def.task {
    (name.value, projectID.value)
} 

lazy val subListTask = subList := {
  nameAndProjectID.all(ScopeFilter()).value.foreach { case (name, id) =>
   println(s"Subproject ${id}, $name")
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm still quite new to sbt API. Please, can you elaborate the idea to the context in question (update section). What if I have a list of projects instead of predefined `projectID`?

Comment: just put the code I've given between the `object CustomTasks {` and `}` and that should work. The `projectID` and `name` are just keys (you have to import them with `import sbt.Keys._`). See how `projectID` is defined  http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.4/sxr/Keys.scala.html#326619

Answer (score 6):

See [Scopes](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Scopes.html). Project is one of three axes of a key. You can get `name` from a sub project as:

```
(name in sub_project1).value
```

Comment: When I do this inside a task I get "Illegal dynamic reference".